# Can I automatically login to youtube using UIWebView (iOS)?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, autologin

I have a question about authentication with UIWebView. I want to login in webview, but without webview interface. Is it possible?
For example I will be using UITextField for user login and password. After the user enters a user name and password, the program will automatically log in and save the user's session.
Is it possible to login without providing UIWebView interface?

I was able to parse the html page, but if the html changes, I can't correctly parse the new html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youtube has - like most google products - a pretty well documented API to access nearly everything on their site through API calls.

Check http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/youtube/overview.html

Comment: Thanks! Now I used Gdata library. This library has service for login. But I don't know how this service work. I need to figure out how to login a user request via post request with user login and password parameter.

Comment: There is plenty of sample code on the site and even an Objective-C library that wraps all the API calls for you: http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/

Comment: Well maybe I missed something that, when analyzed Youtube API. Objective-C library is best library which i used. I just thought that there is a way to just use authorization for user without large library for this.

Comment: Well, you don't need to use the library. But you can look at the code to see how they access the API. If it is just the login query you need, look at that code and reimplement it if you don't want to ship the whole library